# Orbeon Forms XForms questions

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am evaluating XForms for a project, and specifically looking at Orbeon XForms implementation, I have following questions, which I would like to ask the community of users already using the technology.

1. What are the known limitations of XForms if any?
2. Is there a feature comparison to HTML forms?
3. For rich UI can we use JavaScript, in combination with xforms ? E.g. if I need autocomplete feature on UI, can it be done with XForms or we can use JavaScript libraries for the same?
4. another example, is date picker control on UI, Can it be done with XForms? or do I need to use JavaScript libraries?
5. Forms which are designed using the Orbeon Forms Builder, do they adhere to XForms spec? Or does it put some Orbeon specific features? I.e. are they portable to another XForms implementation?

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably off-topic for StackOverflow: too general, subjective, and covering too much ground. This said, a few hints:

1. If limitations there are, they are probably not directly linked to XForms proper but to specific implementations.
2. I don't know of anything really up to date.
3. With Orbeon specifically: yes. UI controls and can use JavaScript. For example the built-in autocomplete control does use JavaScript. Custom components can as well integrate with JavaScript.
4. With Orbeon specifically: a date picker is built-in.
5. This [FAQ](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/FAQ-~-Orbeon-Form-Builder-and-Orbeon-Form-Runner#can-the-forms-designed-with-form-builder-run-in-other-xforms-engines) covers this. Short answer: no.

I recommend you have a look at the [Form Builder Controls](http://demo.orbeon.com/orbeon/fr/orbeon/controls/new) to see what built-in controls are available.